# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, func

Tags: comments, comments-template

I have installed Wordpress in my localhost server. I am a creating custom menu. When I try to remove the existing "primary" menu from it, I get this error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'tnc-remove_default_menu' not found or invalid function name in F:\AppServ\www\itexperthouseen\wp-includes\comment-template.php

inn my admin page. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

My comments.php code is :-

```
        <div id="comments">
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
                <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
            </div><!-- #comments -->
<?php
        return;
    endif;
?>

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
            <h3 id="comments-title">
            <?php comments_number(__('No comments','tie'), __('One comment','tie'), '% '.__('comments','tie') );?>
            </h3>

<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :  ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'tie' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'tie' ) ); ?></div>
            </div> <!-- .navigation -->
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php $comments_by_type = &separate_comments($comments); ?>
            <?php if ( !empty($comments_by_type['comment']) ) : ?>
                <ol class="commentlist"><?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=custom_comments'); ?></ol>
            <?php endif; ?>    
            <?php $comment_counter = 0 ; ?>
            <?php if ( !empty($comments_by_type['pings']) ) : ?>
            <div id="pings" class="commentlist">
                <ol class="pinglist"><?php wp_list_comments('type=pings&trackback&pingback&callback=custom_pings'); ?></ol>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?> 
<?php else : 
    if ( ! comments_open() ) :
?>
    <?php __( 'Comments are closed.', 'tie' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php

$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'tie' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'tie' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'tie' ) . '</label>' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
);
$required_text = __(' Required fields are marked', 'tie').' <span class="required">*</span>';
?>
<?php comment_form( array(
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' , 'tie' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
    'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf( __( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>'  , 'tie' ), admin_url( 'profile.php' ), $user_identity, wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
    'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' . __( 'Your email address will not be published.'  , 'tie' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) . '</p>',
    'title_reply' => __( 'Leave a Reply'  , 'tie' ),
    'title_reply_to' => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s'  , 'tie' ),
    'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Cancel reply'  , 'tie' ),
    'label_submit' => __( 'Post Comment'  , 'tie' )
)); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: Sometimes these error messages are misleading. It has nothing to do with your core comments.php file. Check this function, `tnc-remove_default_menu`, you most probably mis-spelled it in your `add_action` call back. Your function and callback should be exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that function `tnc-remove_default_menu` is not defined anywhere in your code. (You shouldn't use `-` character in function name in PHP).

So most probably there is a function called `tnc_remove_default_menu`, and you've misspelled it's name in `add_action`/`add_filter`.

If there is no such function anywhere in your code, then you should remove this filter/action (if this function is not needed and you don't use it) or implement this function (if you want to use it).